# Feature 'target-typed object creation' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater

Tags: c#, .net, c#-9.0

I get an error in this line:

```cs
MessageParser<BestLimit> parser = new(() => new BestLimit());
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Feature 'target-typed object creation' is not available in C# 7.3.
> Please use language version 9.0 or greater

What is this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should write `... = new MessageParser<BestLimit>(...)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unless you're using C# >=9.0 (where target-typed object creation was introduced), you need to specify the type you're creating when using `new`.

Here's the re-written code:

`MessageParser<BestLimit> parser = new MessageParser<BestLimit>(() => new BestLimit());`